# IV weights for binary instrument and discrete treatment

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, treatment-effect

Suppose we have we the structural equation where Y is continuous and T discrete. An example could be $Y$ is wages and $T$ is years of schooling

$$ Y = \alpha + \beta T + u$$

We have a binary excluded instrument $Z$ that monotonically increases $T$ with non-zero first stage at each value of $T$

$$ Z = \gamma + \eta Z + e$$

The IV estimator gives a weighted average of local average treatment effects of shifting people from $T$ to $T'$.

How does the Wald estimator aggregate the different LATEs into one effect? How can we find the weight that specific shifts (for example from 6 to 7 years of schooling) receive in the aggregated estimate?

Comment: For others interested --> Mostly Harmless Econometrics section 4.5.3